# List overflows in HTML

Tags: html, css

I hav created a horizontal menu and a vertical menu,in both cases I noticed that the elements are not rendered properly,the horizontal menu is too large:

```
<ul class="menu-horizontal">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Recent Articles</li>
<li>Email</li>
<li>Resources</li>
<li>Links</li>
</ul>

.menu-horizontal
{
background:blue;
width:926px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
list-style: none;
```

}

```
.menu-horizontal li
{
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
padding:7px 45px;
color:white;
font-size:14px;
border-right:1px solid black;
```

}

I floated a list to the right,in this case I found that the vertical menu does not reach it's left border:

```
.menu-vertical
{
list-style:none;
float:right;
border:1px solid black;
width:200px;
height:auto;
margin-left:10px;
}

.menu-vertical li
{
padding-top:10px;
font-weight:4;
font-size:1.25em;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
color:blue;
background-color: #bfbbc9;
}

<ul class="menu-vertical group">
 <li>Lorem</li> 
 <li>ipsum</li>
 <li>dolor</li>
 <li> sit amet</li>
 <li> consectetur</li>
 <li> adipiscing</li>
 <li> elit</li> 
</ul>
```

The entire HTML and CSS is at a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/bx962/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to remove or override browser defaults, such as padding. E.g.

```
.menu-horizontal {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```